# How can I open a console window at the specified position of the screen?

Tags: windows, command-line, script, automation, console

I need to start several cmd.exe console applications so that they should be positioned on the screen in a particular order - is it possible to do with a .bat file?

I am running Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do it with a batch script, but you can use the following VBScript:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objConfig = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

objConfig.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.X = 100
objConfig.Y = 100

Set objNewProcess = objWMIService.Get("Win32_Process")

intReturn = objNewProcess.Create("cmd.exe", Null, objConfig, intProcessID)
```

It uses the **Win32_ProcessStartup** WMI class - you can [find more details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375(v=vs.85).aspx).

Change the value of *objConfig.X* and *objConfig.Y* to set the X and Y location of where the Command Prompt should open.

Comment: You can also accomplish this with AutoIt, but vbscript might be simpler for this particular task.